# 16" MBP is detecting 2 displays as one, mirroring them

Tags: display, dock

I want 3 independed, extended monitors. The retina on my MBP and 2 displays.

In my current setup this isn't working as expected.

I have 2 DELL2415 connected via a dock, but both are mirrored, while the Retina display is independent.

I have "Mirror displays" unchecked.

[image]

I it almost feels, as if the dock has something to do with it, because it seems like it doesn't matter if one or 2 displays are connected. If I keep the mirror option unchecked it's either extending the MBP display onto 1 or 2 of the DELLs.

Dock "Reg Type No." is K20A001. Also Dell.

Edit: Found somebody with [almost the same problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7961899). No solution however.

---

Comment: Is the setup supported by Apple?  Check the specifications.

Comment: 2 Monitors? What do you mean specifically. I have had 2 monitors on my Macbook countless times.

Comment: Have you tried: Hold the alt/option key while in Display preferences which will add a button called something like “Detect monitors”, click it and see if it detects the separate monitors. What kind of dock are you using?

Comment: > Dock "Reg Type No." is K20A001. Also Dell.

and yes, I tried detecting the monitors